# rqpd commands in r to run panel quantile

Tags: r

I want to run panel quantile for fixed effect in r using rqpd package. I tried running the examples

```
set.seed(10)
m <- 3
s <- as.factor(rep(1:n,rep(m,n)))
x <- exp(rnorm(n*m))
u <- x*rnorm(m*n) + (1-x)*rf(m*n,3,3)
a <- rep(rnorm(n),rep(m,n))
y <- rep(1:n,rep(m,n)) + u 
fit <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 5))
```

But i get the error:

> Error in validObject(.Object) :    invalid class “dsparseModelMatrix”
>   object: superclass "mMatrix" not defined in the environment of the
>   object's class

Comment: Example not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to define n for that example. The original works perfectly fine. To run this package I use R version 2.15.3

`set.seed(10)`
`m <- 3`
`n <- 10`
`s <- as.factor(rep(1:n,rep(m,n)))`
`x <- exp(rnorm(n*m))`
`u <- x*rnorm(m*n) + (1-x)*rf(m*n,3,3)`
`a <- rep(rnorm(n),rep(m,n))`
`y <- a + u`
`fit <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 5))`
`sfit <- summary(fit)`

Answer (score -1):

Did you install the MatrixModels package?  You need that before you can run rqpd.